# Как написать правильнее?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Распоряжение о назначении постоянно действующих инвентаризационных комиссий или  Распоряжение о назначении постоянно действующих инвентаризационных комиссиях?

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант верен, во втором нужно либо исправить падежи (тогда он совпадёт с первым), либо для согласования с имеющимися падежами ("распоряжение о комиссиях") исключить слово "назначение" (тогда выражение станет менее конкретным: можно будет понимать любые распоряжения, касающиеся таких комиссий).

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо)))